# Use array to make a d3.map

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am studying this [example of d3](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606). Currently, the example reads data from `unemployment.tsv`:

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv", function(d) { unemployment.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready);
```

However, I would prefer to save data in an array variable and use it.

```
var idRates = [
  ["01001","5.1"],
  ["01003","4.9"],
  ... ...
]
```

Does anyone know how to modify the code and use this `idRates`? I guess we need to use `idRates` to make `unemployment` which is a `d3.map`...

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xw7IzWgtofWAWDSr6aut) with a part of data...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make a `d3.map` from your array, we can do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < idRates.length; i++){
  unemployment.set(idRates[i][0], +idRates[i][1]);
}
```

We are essentially setting the properties in the map just the way we were doing it from the `tsv` data while iterating over your array.

Also, since we are not using the `tsv` file anymore, I have removed the line that loads it.

```
d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://d3js.org/us-10m.v1.json")
    //.defer(d3.tsv, "unemployment.tsv", function(d) { unemployment.set(d.id, +d.rate); })
    .await(ready);
```

Check forked Plunkr here - https://plnkr.co/edit/wHEbk4faWyyvWHG1TrHU?p=preview